# marionetteItemView Childview, events not triggered

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

So this is the code on the ParentView:
relevant method:

```
openChildView: function(){

    var childView = new ChildView({
            container: $container //container where the child map should be appended
    });

    childView.show();
}
```

this is the code of the ChildView:

```
    ChildView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        template: _.template($(templates_c).filter('#my_child_view_template').html()),

        ui: {
            saveButton: 'button.js-save',
            uploadButton: 'button.js-upload',
            deleteButton: 'button.js-discard'
        },
        events: {
            'click @ui.saveButton': function() {
                log.debug('save');
            },
            'click @ui.uploadButton': function() {
                log.debug('upload');
            },
            'click @ui.deleteButton': function() {
                log.debug('delete');
            }
        },
        show: function() {
            this.render();
        },

        initialize: function(){
            this.container = this.options.container;
            this.id = this.options.id;
        },

        remove: function(){
            // Don't know yet if this is the proper way, but for now it works
            this.container.find('.container-child-view').remove();
        },

        render: function(){
            this.container.append(this.template({
                id: this.id,
                img: '...'
            }));

            log.debug('on render');
            this.bindUIElements();
            this.delegateEvents();

            return this;
        }
    });
```

this is the code of the template of the ChildView:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="my_child_view_template">
    <div class="block container-child-view">
        <div class="block-title">
            <h4><%= id %></h4>
        </div>

        <div class="img">
            <img src="<%= imgUrl %>">
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                <button id="discard" type="button" class="js-discard btn btn-alt btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Cancel</button>
                <button id="upload" type="button" class="js-upload btn btn-alt btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload</button>
                <button id="save" type="button" class="js-save btn btn-alt btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

The childView is being rendered on top of the parentview but no events are triggered on it (save, discard, upload).

Any hints/ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `.delegateEvents()` binds events is by delegating to the view's `el`. In the [source](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1240) you'd see this:

```
delegate: function(eventName, selector, listener) {
  this.$el.on(eventName + '.delegateEvents' + this.cid, selector, listener);
},
```

As you can see the jQuery `.on()` is invoked on the view's `$el`. If a `selector` argument is passed to `.delegate()` (like, say `.js-save`) that selector's events are delegated to its containing view's `el`.

The way you override `.render()` you chose to substitute the "all-mighty" `this.el` for `this.container`. Invoking `this.delegateElements()` still calls `.delegate()` to do the binding on `this.el`, while your view *actually* lives in `this.container`. The view events are bubbling up to an unbound container.

A quick fix may be to override render like this:

```
    render: function(){
        this.container.append(this.template({
            id: this.id,
            img: '...'
        }));

        log.debug('on render');
        this.bindUIElements();

        // .setElement is an internal method that will
        // make your container the view's el and will call
        // .delegateEvents on this new el
        this.setElement();

        return this;
    }
});
```

I probably can't call myself an upright Marionette community denizen unless I also provided you a more framework-oriented solution. It looks to me that you've overriden `.render` because you want to **1.** render the `ItemView` into a specific containing element and **2.** you want to load non-model data into your template.

#### 1. Setting the view `el`

Backbone will take an existing DOM element for a view's `el`. Just pass in a selector or a jQuery object on the view's instantiation,

```
var childView = new ChildView({ el: $container });
```

The Marionette `.render()` method will attach the view to that `$container`.

#### 2. Passing in non-model data to your template

Marionette has this handy view utility, [`templateHelpers`](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.0/marionette.view.html#viewtemplatehelpers), that lets you put data in the scope of the template renderer. The data can be any JS object, including functions. Just include the property in your view.

```
templateHelpers: function () {
    return {
      img: function(){
        return 'http://some-domain.com/img/" + this.id;
      },

      id: this.id
    };
  }
});
```

where, in this version of the `templateHelper` `this` is the context of the view.